# Time Zones in Java / GWT (Client-side)

Tags: java, gwt

**[Client-side GWT class]**

I have a Date Object...

```
Date dataObject = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                      .parse("2009-10-12T00:00:00.000);
```

This works fine. However when I do a:

```
dateObject.getTime();
```

It returns a UNIX Time milliseconds using a GMT with daylight savings, therefore making it a UNIX Time I cannot use. I need it in UTC. How do I do this?

---

Currently I'm parsing a date and it is giving me back:

```
'Thu Apr 16 08:46:20 GMT+100 2009' @ '1239867980191'
```

However the date I'm passing in is 1 hour less than this time (7:46 and not 8:46!).

**How do I pass in the fact it's UTC? Or if it can't use UTC (which would be ridiculous), how do I use GMT without the daylight savings?**

Comment: There's no concept of "UNIX Time (in) milliseconds using a GMT with daylight savings".  The number of milliseconds elapsed since the 'epoch' is fixed and is unrelated to GMT and/or daylight savings.  You may either be feeding a wrongly formatted time string and/or forgetting to precise if you're using daylight savings or not or be wrongly converting back your time in milliseconds to another format.  But the number of milliseconds since the epoch (used both by Java and by Unix and by a lot of other technologies) is completely agnostic to GMT and to daylight savings.

Comment: OldEnthusiast : this should be an answer.

Comment: Well you certainly get the Pedant of the day award.

Comment: Not really pendantry: ‘epoch+DST’ isn't a real timestamp format that's used in GWT or anywhere. `getTime` returns you plain time since UTC epoch as expected; if DST/timezone is changing the results then there's a problem elsewhere, eg. in the parse step.

Comment: Yes, I would have thought that was obvious. I'm not trying to change the `getTime`, I'm trying to add the TimeZone to the parse... which just isn't working the way I'm doing it. hence the question `I need it in UTC. How do I do this?`. I would have pasted what I've already came up with, however I doubt people would want to read 30 different combinations of the same thing.

Comment: What happens when you have 2009-10-12T00:00:00.000-04:00?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last edit makes things clearer.

Basically, you are confused, and you already get what you want.

1239867980191 milliseconds since the Epoch translates to Thursday, April 16th, 2009, at 7:46:20.191 in the GMT time zone. The very same instant translates to the same day, but 8:46:20.191 in the GMT+01 time zone. If your input string specified "7:46:20.191" and you indeed got 1239867980191 from `Date.getTime()` then congratulations, the parsing code understood your "7:46:20.191" as to be interpreted in the GMT time zone, and did it properly.

If *afterwards* you get "8:46:20" when printing, this is only because you use the GMT+01 time zone for displaying that instant. Note that the string contains `GMT+100` precisely to notify you that it uses that time zone for display purposes. The *instant* which the `Date` instance represents is nonetheless exactly the instant you wish it to contain. Remember that a `Date` instance represents an instant in time, for which no notion of time zone applies: time zones are used to convert instants into calendar elements (days, hours...) and back.

To convert a `Date` to a displayable string, use `DateTimeFormat.format(Date, TimeZone)` which lets you specify which time zone you want to use for that string.

Comment: +1 for nice clarification and pointing to `DateTimeFormat.format(Date, TimeZone)`

Comment: Wow, this has been one confusing situation. It seems you are correct. Thanks for the extra clarity :)

Answer (score 3):

Since the `Calendar` class is not supported in GWT, maybe something hackish like this will work:

```
final String timezone = "GMT-07:00";
DateTimeFormat dtf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ");
long unix = dtf.parse("2009-10-12T00:00:00" + timezone).getTime();
```

This way you can provide the correct timezone info - though, that should be the default behaviour.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was trying. However I couldn't get a right combination at all. I would have thought the time zone code would be "UTC" for UTC? Isn't -7:00 California or something?

Comment: I added `"GMT-07:00"` as an example, you should change to whatever value is working for you ;] (so that you get your "UNIX Time milliseconds using a GMT with daylight savings" ;))

Answer (score 1):

It is the other way round. A `Date` instance holds the time in milliseconds since the Epoch, using the UTC time scale (i.e. leap seconds are ignored). This is what `Date.getTime()` returns and that's what you want.

The culprit here is the parser, which interprets the date you give as a string in your local time zone. If you want `DateTimeFormat` to interpret the string as a date-and-time given in the UTC time zone, append an explicit time zone to the parsed string:

```
DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ")
    .parse("2009-10-12T00:00:00.000" + " GMT");
```

(The above assumes that I understood GWT documentation properly; I have not tried.)

Just to be clear in my notations: for all practical purposes, there is no difference between "GMT" and "UTC", and there is no daylight saving in the GMT time zone. Other time zones are often defined as "GMT plus or minus some offset" and the offset may change between summer and winter. For instance, the time zone in New York is somewhat equivalent to "GMT-04" in summer and "GMT-05" in winter.

Comment: I think GMT automatically includes daylight savings - which is what I do not want. I want plain UTC or normal GMT.

Comment: @_bravado: It doesn't, hence why Britain uses BST in summer.

Comment: Well I don't know what your doing, but for me - I'm telling Java it needs to be GMT and it's making it Summertime. So I repeat, it **doesn't**, or maybe you or whoever else disagrees cares to explain their answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

I keep seeing formats with ZZZZ being suggested... but why?

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" would match

"2009-10-12T00:00:00.000-0000"

The last part being the offset from UTC; California (to use someone else's example time) would be -0800, -0700 in summer.

As a side note, GMT is also always -0000.  That's why Britain's summer time zone is BST (British Summer Time, +0100).

Comment: I'm passing in a Timestamp extracted from a file that is in UTC. I'm passing it in with your suggestions - and it is converting it to GMT Summertime - yet again. Either you're not considering GWT Client-Side or something is fundamentally wrong with my GWT - which is the latest release.

Answer (score -4):

Try the [Calendar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date dataObject = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                  .parse("2009-10-12T00:00:00.000);
cal.setTime(dataObject);
cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

According to the API, getTimeInMillis() returns "the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch."

**EDIT**: as _bravado pointed out, the Calendar API is currently not available for GWT ([Issue 603](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=603)).  While this would get the appropriate time in a Java application, it isn't going to work here.  There is information in the [group](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/d06b87ca2005fa09/b804f1f2c7be0b57?lnk=gst&q=Date+serialization&rnum=6#b804f1f2c7be0b57) about using GMT.

**EDIT**: Missing a closing bracket on the the Calendar.getInstance() call

Comment: I don't think you can use Calendar with GWT?