# Getting a GWT timestamp in UTC format

Tags: gwt

I am trying to get the current timestamp and convert it into a UTC date for an XML file.

I am using this

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat;

DateTimeFormat.format( new Date(), TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

but am getting the following error

> The method format(Date, TimeZone) in
>   the type DateTimeFormat is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Date,
>   TimeZone)

I need the output as "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ"

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155469/time-zones-in-java-gwt-client-side

Answer (score 3):

Use [`com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZone.createTimeZone(0)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/TimeZone.html#createTimeZone%28int%29) to create a UTC TimeZone object, and then use that in [`DateTimeFormat.format(Date, TimeZone)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/shared/DateTimeFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date,%20com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.TimeZone%29).

Answer (score 2):

You can use apostrophe to indicate literals in a DateTimeFormat pattern.
eg. `"HH'o''clock'"`

So, the formatter you need would look something like this:

```
DateTimeFormat formatter = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
```

I tried it out. It gave me an output in format **2010-16-29T08:16:23+0530**

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: close, but is that your local time?  I need UTC.  It should looke something like this 2010-11-29T10:17:00Z

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZone instead of java.util.TimeZone

Comment: That solves that part of the problem, the above code still does not work though, do you know how to format the current data into UTC in GWT?